# How do I find a package providing a file (cross distro)

Tags: package-management, distributions

I want to check from script if a command exists and suggest installation of the corresponding package if necessary.

On Debian systems I use `dpgk` to look for packages providing some specific file, e.g.:

```
$ dpkg -S */envsubst
gettext-base: /usr/bin/envsubst
```

Is there some solution that works on all Linux systems, or at least the most common ones?

Some open source library is welcome as well if there is not a few-liner.

Comment: Ubuntu does this.  Type in a command, and, if it's not found, automatically recommends which package(s) to possibly install.  Unfortunately, my Google-fu can't find how it works.

Comment: @RonJohn `cnf` aka. `command-not-found`

Answer (score 2):

On distributions supporting PackageKit, you can use that:

```
$ pkcon search file envsubst
Searching by file             [=========================]
Starting                      [=========================]
Loading cache                 [=========================]
Querying                      [=========================]
Finished                      [=========================]
Installed       gettext-base-0.21-4.amd64 (installed:debian-stable-main)        GNU Internationalization utilities for the base system
Installed       git-1:2.30.2-1+deb11u2.amd64 (installed:debian-stable-security-main)   fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
```

Unfortunately for more reliable results across distributions you need to specify the full path, which means in your case you’d have to try various possible installation locations. Thus on Debian:

```
$ pkcon search file /usr/bin/envsubst
Searching by file             [=========================]         
Loading cache                 [=========================]         
Querying                      [=========================]         
Finished                      [=========================]         
Installed       gettext-base-0.21-4.amd64 (installed:debian-stable-main)        GNU Internationalization utilities for the base system
```

and on RHEL 8:

```
$ pkcon search file /usr/bin/envsubst
Searching by file             [=========================]         
Finished                      [=========================]         
Installed       gettext-0.19.8.1-17.el8.x86_64 (installed:anaconda)             GNU libraries and utilities for producing multi-lingual messages
Available       gettext-0.19.8.1-14.el8.x86_64 (rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms)  GNU libraries and utilities for producing multi-lingual messages
```

Many distributions also install `command-not-found` which will tell you how to make a given command available, if possible, or suggest typo candidates.

Comment: Oh! I feel like a newb, never new about pkcon. At least on my fedora 37, you do have to specify the full path of the file you're interested in: `pkcon search file envsubst` yields no results; `pkcon search file /usr/bin/envsubst` does tell me about the gettext-envsubst package. Sadly, `pkcon search` seems to reject globs and regexes.

Comment: Yes, `pkcon search` is rather limited — it’s a thin shim over the underlying packaging system. I hadn’t tested on RHEL or Fedora, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: mehh, I went to `http//www.packagekit.org` as listed in the pkcon man page in hopes to figure out whether prepending `*/` to the search pattern if on a `dnf repoquery` distro would be an easy solution to these behavioral differences. That domain got occupied by a third party :(

Comment: Thanks so far! There does not seem to be a simple solution. With `pkcon` (hopefully that it actually is installed on the target distribution) you need to know the cross distri paths. Without, you might get improper results. Further more also the "machine readable" output has to be parsed. Well, it could be a workaround to give the user some hint where to find the requirements. However, I'ld like some precise end-user instruction similar to the `command-not-found` output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org) web service online, as it supports most distros you'd ever want, not affiliated but very useful

If you want it from the CLI, you can subscribe to the API for $5 a month and build a small bash function to connect to it